# Why are my export files different from my Indesign artboards?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, pdf, export, artboard

I'm trying to figure out why on my exported files, some pages have crossed over onto each other. They are outside the bleed line so I expect them to be trimmed however, some tutorials, etc do not have this issue. What am I doing wrong? This is the first time I'm using InDesign.

NB: I exported files from AI to InDesign as InDesign is not a part of my skillset, I was doing someone a favor.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tUew.jpg - PDF Version
https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4Ypr.png - InDesign Version
https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4ymQ.png - PDF Version
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDKK9.png - InDesign Version

Comment: Note that InDesign does not have artboards – it has **pages**, since it’s a page layout program.

Comment: Bleeds **should** extend into the opposite page when outputting single pages with bleeds. This is done *intentionally* to ensure the single pages can be imposed correctly for printer spreads. Your images all appear **correct**.

Answer (score 1):

You are saving the PDF with crop marks and bleeds included, which is optional and only useful when sending a PDF to a print shop.

**If that's your intention**, then the PDF is fine, and you should not be concerned with the issue. This is how InDesign will save a single page PDF with crop marks and bleeds, and the print shop has probably seen this before. Excess artwork flows into the facing page's bleed area, but all this is supposed to be removed during production.

Another solution here is to change the document from FACING PAGES to SINGLE PAGES in the `Main Menu → File → Document Setup` panel. Be advised doing this can potentially have other effects on your pages, so only use this if you have full control of your document.

However, **if you need to remove these crop marks and bleeds**, when you save the PDF, in the Export dialog box, **unselect** all the boxes marked in red below. Make sure they are **not** selected, and try again.

[image: editing]